# Android Studio ActionBarActivity not working after trying to import a JAR library

Tags: import, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-actionbaractivity

I have the latest **Android Studio** running and I also made it to run my first app without any problem.

Then I wanted to add gson library to use in my project but I must have done something wrong because since then my ap does not work any longer since this import fails:

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
```

I have also added this now for `gson` in my `gradle` file:

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
...
```

I did:

- Invalidate cache and restart
- delete my .gradle folder

But nothing works.

Do you have any idea what I might have mixed up?

Thanx for your help!!!

These are the files:
Build.gradle project:

```
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0-rc4'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Build.gradle (app):

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xxxxx"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.2'
}
```

The error that comes is "Cannot resolve symbol 'ActionBarActivity'"

After a gradle sync it looks fine but when I then try to run my project, that ActionBarActivity s again not recognized ... but it was before...

#

Now I have deleted the .iml file and the .idea folder and re-imported my project.

It looks good but now Android Studio is unable to install the .apk on my device when I want to run it:

[Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28242646/android-studio-failure-install-failed-invalid-apk)

(so I opened a new question...)

Comment: Can you post the "build.gradle" files from your project.  Also, can you post more on what error messages you are specifically getting and when.  This kind of problem can be caused by not including the dependency for the library containing ActionBarActivity.

Comment: Thanks for posting the extra info.  I don't see any problems.  I created a test project with the same dependencies and didn't get the error.  There are new versions of the libraries and the gradle plugin that you could upgrade to just in case.