# Android Studio: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK]

Tags: android-studio

I have the following problem when running my app:

```
Waiting for device.
Target device: samsung-gt
Uploading file
    local path: C:\Users\kwmaster\AndroidStudioProjects\Count500\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk
    remote path: /data/local/tmp/xxxxx
Installing xxxxx
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/xxxxx"
pkg: /data/local/tmp/xxxxx
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK]
```

Why did it not let me install the apk???

Comment: Can you post your build.gradle file?

Comment: You were right - the problem was he gradle version in my build.gradle file - now it works as requested :-)

Answer (score 6):

In my case (I have a rooted device) and when I rooted, something happened with my `permission of /data/local/tmp` and they have been changed, so `adb` can't get access  `temp` file.

How I solved it:

1. Install RootExplorer
2. Create new `tmp` folder on SD card
3. Long press on `tmp` folder, and select "Link to this folder" (last option in menu)
4. Go to `/data/local/` and tap button "Create link" from bottom

Answer (score 4):

For those that will encounter this problem in the future just go in **build.gradle** and put at ***applicationId*** just put a name with a point betwen 2 words.Example: ***First.Test***

Comment: I just upgraded to 3.6.1 and attempted to run my application and got thi error.  For the applicationId I have "com.salinas.abuilder", once I changed it to two terms it appears to work again :)

Comment: Now that I changed the ID, my google maps no longer work?  Argh, I thought this was an upgrade :(

Answer (score 0):

As AndroidGuy thought there was a problem in build.gradle - the gradle version ws wrong.
I also have changed in the settings to use the default gradle wrapper and not the local stuff!!!

Answer (score 0):

I was also having this problem because of changing package name. So do check your package and sub packages names and also in manifest file where activities defined with package name.

Answer (score 0):

when I cd /data/local/tmp, I found my project name in the folder.
So I solved the problem as follows:

1. adb shell
2. cd /data/local/tmp
3. rm -r your project name.  For example:  rm com.example.pc002.intenttest1

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar issue. I fixed it by first closing the Android Studio project and then deleting the .gradle folder within the project.This, forced Android Studio to rebuild it when I opened it again, and then it fixed the issue.